# Access Docker container running on OS X via boot2docker in Windows virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtualbox, boot2docker

### Overview:

Host: Mac OS X running boot2docker and Docker
Guest: Windows 7

### The Problem:

For my web-development I have set up a docker container via boot2docker on OS X. Within OS X I can access my docker services via boot2docker.

Running `boot2docker ip`, I get:

```
The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103
```

I am running a Django application on port 1234 (I have mapped the port 5000 on the docker image to port 1234 on my Mac) which I can access within OS X in an web-browser via the address `192.168.59.103:1234`. Everything works fine in OS X.

Now I have to test the Web stuff on IE which is why I have downloaded IE8, IE10 and so forth via Microsofts modern.IE website. As a result I have some more VirtualBox images, which are running Windows 7 and come with the propriate IE version.

The question is now how to access the Docker container in those Windows instances to test it under several IE versions.

### What I have done so far:

#### Idea 1

To access the Django application I have looked up my local IP address and tried to access it via NAT in the Windows guests. Given my local IP adress `192.168.178.24`, I have tried to access `192.168.178.24:1234` from Windows. Although I can ping `192.168.178.24` from Windows, I do get only a timeout on the port `1234`.

#### Idea 2

Boot2docker runs a VirtualBox machine called `boot2docker-vm`. It comes with two network adapters, NAT and a host-only adapter called `vboxnet0`. The latter has the address `192.168.59.3` (which is the one which `boot2docker ip` returns) with the network mask `255.255.255.0`. It runs a DHCP-Server on Server Adress `192.168.59.99` which gives addresses from `192.168.59.103-254`.

I have added a second network adapter for my Windows guest systems which can also access via a host-only adapter the network `vboxnet0`. When being connected to the network the Windows machines do get a valid IP and **can** ping the IP `192.168.59.103`. But I cannot connect to my Django instance on port `1234`. If I try to call `192.168.59.103:1234` within Windows, I get a timeout.

Why is it not possible to connect to the Django instance? Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902267/boot2docker-connect-to-container-over-lan?rq=1).
To get access to the Django instance I had to open the port on the `boot2docker-vm` machine.

This can be done by either by `boot2docker-vm → settings → Network → Adapter 1 (NAT) → Port Forwarding` and add a new rule where `Host IP`and `Guest IP` can be left empty and `Host Port` and `Guest Port` should be set to `1234`.

Another way to do so is executing the following command in the command line

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port1234,tcp,,1234,,1234";
```

Of course this needs to be done for all ports, if more than one port is being used.